# Installer signing

Tags: installation, signing

What are ramification of installer signing. I would like to know what happens when I sign my installer with for example VeriSign certificate and my subscription period ends. Will there be warning about it during installation. If yes, what if I pay for another subscription period, will this message disappear or I will have to create new installer and sign it with new file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you also timestamp when signing, it will still show as valid after the certificate expires.